# using sauce and protractor to test internet explorer and safari

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, saucelabs

I have the following tests, which run fine when I run them locally and on sauce (at least most of the time) using firefox and chrome.

```
ptor = protractor.getInstance();

baseUrl = protractor.getInstance().params.sBaseUrl;
aRequiredTextFieldsKeys = [
'sFirstName',
'sLastName',
'sStreet',
'sZip',
'sCity'
];


describe('form', function ()
{
var sFormUrl = baseUrl + '#/form';

beforeEach(function ()
{
    ptor.get(sFormUrl);
});


describe('wholeForm', function ()
{

    it('fully filled form => required fields have correct class && submit leads to other route', function ()
    {

        function checkRequiredClass(el)
        {
            expect(el.getAttribute('class')).toContain('ng-valid-required');
        }

        // requried text-fields
        for (var i = 0; i < aRequiredTextFieldsKeys.length; i++) {
            var el = element(by.model('oFormData.' + aRequiredTextFieldsKeys[i]));
            el.sendKeys('a');
            checkRequiredClass(el);
        }

        // email
        var elEmail = element(by.model('oFormData.sEmail'));
        elEmail.sendKeys('jo@jo.de');
        checkRequiredClass(el);

        // birthday
        var elBirthday = element(by.model('oFormData.oBirthday'));
        elBirthday.sendKeys('1.1.1995');
        checkRequiredClass(el);

        // checkboxes
        var elCheck1 = element(by.model('oFormData.bAgb'));
        elCheck1.click();
        checkRequiredClass(elCheck1);

        var elCheck2 = element(by.model('oFormData.bPrivatePolicy'));
        elCheck2.click();
        checkRequiredClass(elCheck2);
        // hack upload bon
        ptor.executeScript(function ()
        {
            var scope = $('#application-form-id').scope();
            scope.oFormData.bBonUploaded = true;
        });

        // submit form
        element(by.className('btn-submit')).click();

        ptor.getCurrentUrl()
            .then(function (url)
            {
                expect(url).toNotBe(sFormUrl);
            });
    });
 });
```

But when I launch internet explorer or safari, I get all sorts of errors, while the page works fine when tested manually. For IE I get:

> Message:
>        UnknownError: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 97
>   milliseconds Build info: version: '2.30.0', revision: 'dc1ef9c', time:
>   '2013-02-19 00:15:27' System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2',
>   os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_35' Session
>   ID: 42b30348-8598-4edb-923e-a7019ced6eb0 Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, elementScrollBehavior=0, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false,
>   browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=10,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false,
>   requireWindowFocus=false, allowAsynchronousJavaScript=false,
>   handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=, nativeEvents=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]
>
> Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {"stack":"TypeError: 
>   Unable to  get property 'get' of undefined or null reference\n   at Anonymous function (Unknown 
>   script code:25:5)\n   at Anonymous function (Unknown script code:21:14)\n   at Anonymous 
>   function  (Unknown script code:21:2)","description":"Unable to get property 'get' of undefined 
>   or null reference","number":-2146823281}

And for Safari:

> UnknownError: Detected a page unload event; script execution does not work across page loads. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 384 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_35'
>   Session ID: null
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, secureSsl=true, browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, version=5.1.7}]

I'm confsued about the reasons. I tried simpler tests with the same results, I tried local and remote urls and I tried all sorts of delays like `waitForAngular`, `wait` and `ptor ignoreAsynch = true`. None of them lead to the desired outcome. Any suggestions?

My protractor config file:

```
// A reference configuration file.
    exports.config = {

        seleniumServerJar: null,
        seleniumPort: null,
        chromeOnly: false,
        // Additional command line options to pass to selenium. For example,
        // if you need to change the browser timeout, use
        // seleniumArgs: ['-browserTimeout=60'],
        seleniumArgs: [],
        sauceUser: 'saucesuer',
        sauceKey: 'key',
        allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
        specs: [
            'test/e2e/**/*.js',
        ],

        // https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
        // https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/capabilities.js
        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'phantomjs',
            'phantomjs.binary.path':'node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs'
        },


        // Selector for the element housing the angular app - this defaults to
        // body, but is necessary if ng-app is on a descendant of <body>
        rootElement: 'body',

        onPrepare: function ()
        {
    //        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
        },

        params: {
            sBaseUrl: 'https://dev.com/'

        },
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',

        framework: 'jasmine',

        // ----- Options to be passed to minijasminenode -----
        //
        // See the full list at https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode
        jasmineNodeOpts: {
            // onComplete will be called just before the driver quits.
            onComplete: null,
            // If true, display spec names.
            isVerbose: true,
            // If true, print colors to the terminal.
            showColors: true,
            // If true, include stack traces in failures.
            includeStackTrace: true,
            // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
        }
    };
```

WHile it doesnt seem to matter, I use grunt-protractor runner to run multiple instances sequentially.

```
           chrome: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: 'chrome',
                    "idle-timeout": 120
                }
            }
        },
        firefox: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: 'firefox'
                }
            }
        },
        ie9: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: 'internet explorer',
                    version: '9',
                    "idle-timeout": 120
                }
            }
        },
        ie10: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: 'internet explorer',
                    version: '10'
                }
            }
        },
        safari7: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: 'safari',
                    version: '7'
                }
            }
        },
        safari6: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: 'safari',
                    version: '6'
                }
            }
        },
        safari5: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: 'safari',
                    version: '5'
                }
            }
        }
    }

grunt.registerTask('e2eall', [
    'protractor:ie9',
    'protractor:ie10',
    'protractor:safari5',
    'protractor:safari6',
    'protractor:safari7',
    'protractor:firefox',
    'protractor:chrome'
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hugo,
This is an issue with certain test configurations that was partially solved in Protractor 0.17 and more definitively solved in 0.18. I would recommend updating your protractor to latest (**0.18.1** at the time of this post) and seeing if that solves your issue.

Relevant changelog entries:

## v0.18

> (10aec0f) fix(pageload): increase wait timeout
>
> The 300 ms wait caused problems when testing IE on Sauce Labs. It seems way too short. "browser.get()" invariably timed out. Increasing it solved our problem.

## v0.17

> (a0bd84b) fix(pageload): add a wait during protractor.get() to solve unload issues
>
> Some systems would not wait for the browser unload event to finish before beginning the asynchronous script execution.
>
> Closes #406. Closes #85.

Hope that helps!